# Android RecyclerView : on item, insert push up instead of down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Say I have a RecyclerView containing a lot of item views: `[a, b, c, d, e, ...]`. If I want to insert a new ItemView `X` between `b` and `c`, I update my underlying collection and call `notifyItemInserted(2)`. I now have `[a, b, X, c, d, e, ...]`.

My problem is that when `X` appears, it pushes every view *after* itself down (pushing `e` out of screen), and I need it to push every view *before* itself up (pushing `a` out of screen).

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Weird. I'm using a GridLayoutManager and the default behaviour seems to be what you'd like to have and I'm looking for a way to reverse this back to what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because LinearLayoutManager consider start of the list as the anchor position. If you want end of the list to be the anchor position, you can set `stackFromEnd = true;`. In that case, when the list loads for the first time, you'll see;

`V W X Y Z // assuming alphabet is your list of items`

This is the common case for things like conversation apps.

If you want it to start from the beginning while `stackFromEnd` is set to `true`, then you can call `scrollToPosition(0)` when adapter is initialized.

Comment: hey @yigit, I use `stackFromEnd(true)` to maintain correct position when keyboard is shown. But when there are few items in the recyclerview (1 or 2) then the those items were shown at the bottom of the recyclerview with some white space at top. Is there any way to only allow stackfromend if list exceeds the current viewport size?

Comment: sorry, stack form end does not have such settings and we are not planning to add.